# libgdx android VideoView example

Tags: libgdx

I'm new to libgdx and was looking for a solution to play video for the game book I'm creating. After some research I find this article:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30607/play-videos-with-libgdx

However, being naive I do not know where does the splash screen and xml ui code go? Do we implement it in CORE project or android project ?
And if someone can also share the event calling mechanism between CORE and android, that would also really help.
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Your game "Class" files go to the Core project (You write your code once for all platforms).

All your asset files (graphics, sound...) go to Android project > assets . (The desktop project has a link to that assets folder, so you only need to store the assets once).

If you are new to Libgdx, I recommend you to follow basic tutorials like :

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game

http://www.toxsickproductions.com/libgdx/

http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/LibGDX-Tutorial-series.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was related to the article (link) I had. That article talks about splash screen and videoview layout xml file. Do both of them go in core project?

Comment: Ok, sorry. As I saw both go to the Android project. It looks like integrating AdMob. You may get a better understanding about adding a new "view" by looking at this AdMob tutorial : http://www.norakomi.com/tutorial_admob_part2.php#scroll_androidmanifest

Comment: Thanks for clarification, Once I have a working prototype, I will post detail solution.